# RHN Satellite scout won't push

Tags: linux, fedora, centos, rhel

My RHN Satellite (Spacewalk) server is having issues with monitoring. The Spacewalk Monitor Scout will not push out successfully. It always stops with a `Request Expired` status. I can't seem to find any error logs. I don't believe that it is a firewall or SELinux issue.

I can run `/usr/bin/ssh -l nocpulse -p 4545 -i /var/lib/nocpulse/.ssh/nocpulse-identity -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o BatchMode=yes computername /bin/sh -s`

And get results back from the client machine. But from the web console the scout expires. In addition, all of my monitor probes are stuck in an `Awaiting Update` status. The Spacewalk server public key is in the correct location on all clients `/var/lib/nocpulse/.ssh/authorized-keys`. I'm kind of at a loss. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: any takers on this one?

Comment: Have you done a `service iptables stop` and a `setenforce 0` and then tried to see if it would work?

Comment: SELinux and the firewall are not running on both the client and the server

Comment: I am not that familiar with RHN Satellite. But i would do an `strace -fp` on the PID of that monitor to see what is going wrong. Is there really nothing in _/var/log/messages_ about the problem? Are you running this in a VM with limited RAM-resources?

Comment: It is a physical server Dual Core 2.8 Ghz, 4GB RAM, 250GB HDD. When I run the command, nothing is returned, no error, no output